# Native implementation not working

Tags: android, native, codenameone

Trying native Android code with codename one, but same is not working on device. When i try on simulator it is not work also no any message / error. But when same is tried on actual device then got Message `"NO Support"`. It means in `NativeCall nt = NativeLookup.create(NativeCall.class);` through device `nt` is `null`. Is there any mistake in my code ?

NativeImpl code :

```
public class NativeCallImpl extends Activity implements userclasses.NativeCall{

public void setNative(String param) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadData.class);  
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                                  this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);  
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                                  + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Native call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}
}
```

Interface :

```
public interface NativeCall extends NativeInterface{
public void setNative(String mobileNumber);
//public boolean isSupported();
}
```

Call:

```
private void autoUpdate(){
    NativeCall nt= NativeLookup.create(NativeCall.class);
    if(nt!=null){
        nt.setNative(getMobileNumber());
    }else{
        Dialog.show("NO Support", "No Native Support", "OK", null);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of device :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting an exception in the console which you will see if you connect the device cable and run DDMS.

Do not extend `Activity` in the native interface implementation. If you need an Activity add a separate class.

Don't implement the native interface in the impl class. Specifically remove this: `implements userclasses.NativeCall`. It will create issues if you work with peer components...

For more details check out the [developer guide section on native interfaces](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_interfaces).

Comment: you are correct but why below errors while build `Not copying library D:\PR_work\checkInOut\override , it's a directory.
Not copying library D:\PR_work\checkInOut\lib\impl\cls , it's a directory.
Not copying library D:\PR_work\checkInOut\lib\impl\stubs , it's a directory.
Not copying library D:\PR_work\checkInOut\native\internal_tmp , it's a directory.
Not copying library D:\PR_work\checkInOut\native , it's a directory.` is this will include in project or not.

Comment: If i use components of codename one in native code like Dialog.show();, will it work ?

Comment: These aren't errors these are notices from Ant.   You can call Codename One components from native however keep in mind that this is MUCH harder to do in iOS and you need to deal with threading issues as Codename One components must execute on the EDT while native code must execute in their own thread. There is a section on native callbacks in the developer guide link above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a problem with your code, but you can't test native functionality on the simulator. You can use the include sources build option and download the source code and the compile it in Android Studio or XCode and test it in those environments, though.